# Form submit with Post method not working with target _blank in PWA

Tags: reactjs, forms, google-chrome, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps

```
<form
      action="some url"
      method="POST"
      target="_blank"
>
    {_.map(somedata, (value, key: string) => (
     <input name={key} key={key} type="hidden" value={value}/>
      ))}
</form>
```

I am working with a page which submits a form on click of some button, this posts some data and opens a page in a new tab. This works perfectly fine in chrome mobile android but does not work(the new url opens in the new tab but shows no data posted by the form) when i create a PWA shortcut using `Add to Home Screen` feature and submit the form from inside of it. Also the new tab opens inside PWA only instead of mobile android chrome.

Comment: Having the same issue here -- where you able to find a solution?

Comment: I am also having exactly the same issue, searching over Google, still nothing, anyone having a solution please come up quick :)

Comment: its a limitation of PWA app and cannot be solved directly

Answer (score 0):

I apologise that this relates to Jquery (it uses core JS at its heart) but I believe this is something similar to solve the form posting issue. It uses the JS FormData object which allows for files as well.

```
function formPost(form){
    var formData = new FormData();

    $(form).find('input,select,textarea').each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('type') == 'file'){
            use = $(this).get(0).files[0];
        } else {
            use = $(this).val();
        }

        formData.append($(this).attr('name'),use);
    })

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST',$(form).attr('action'));
    request.send(formData);
}
```

Its worth saying that for browsers this requires at least IE10 but I think at end of 2019 we shouldn't be worrying about that !! https://caniuse.com/#search=formdata (PWAs operate in "modern browsers").